# Why does VSCode use so much internet when opened ?? How to disable it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When I open VSCode the internet speed is damn fast and is not allowing me to open new tabs i.e., the new tabs shows no internet. Is there any way to disable the usage of internet by VSCode?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like automatic updates. If you open preferences and search for "update," you'll see a few relevant things:

- `Update: Mode` - how and whether VSCode checks for updates for itself. Options are `none` (never), `manual` (only when you ask it to), `start` (on startup), and `default` (intermittently, including on startup).
- `Extensions: Auto Check Updates` - a tickbox for whether VSCode checks for updates to extensions.
- (Presumably only relevant if the tickbox is checked) `Extensions: Auto Update` - which extensions VSCode should check for updates for: all, only enabled ones, none.